# How to make framework (library?) for personal re-use in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, frameworks, static-libraries

I'm doing a series of book apps for a client.  There's a lot of books in the series, and each one will be a separate app.  Instead of making changes to all the apps every time they want something tweaked in all of them, like the position of a button or something, I'd like to make a universal "framework" (library?) that I can import to a project, just as I would do for one of the iOS SDK's frameworks.  The framework would have all the universal components of the apps, which would include a controller class I would subclass in each app to do the app-specific things.  Then when I need to make changes to all of them, I could just change the code in the framework, and it would affect all the apps that use it.  I'd also like to be able to include common images and other media.

Do I want to use the "Cocoa Touch Static Library" template in Xcode?  I also saw this project in github: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework; would this be a better fit for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your purposes, the simplest approach would simply be to set it up as a static library project.  Then, for each application you want to use it, drag the project into your workspace and add the static library product as a dependent target.

As far as I am aware, the current leading method for building a framework on iOS is [Jeff Verkoeyen's iOS-Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework).

Comment: I thought you couldn't include resources with a static library?  And what's the difference between the link you posted and Xcode's library template?

Comment: You can't include resources with a static framework either (well, there are hacks, but not in the traditional manner).  The typical approach is to also build a bundle that developers drag into their project.  The project I linked to goes into detail about the various tradeoffs between different approaches.  One difference between a static library and a framework is that the framework includes the headers, so you don't have to mess with the header path settings in your project.

Comment: I guess bundle is what I'm looking for.  Is there a way to have a centralized version of it, so if I want to update all the apps that use it I can just change the original?